# How to replace IP Addresses as strings in a list to sort strings in python with checking out the repetitions between IP Addresses

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, replace

If I have a list has the format below:

```
List1 = ['0.0.0.0', '192.168.1.193', '192.168.1.120', '10.0.0.155', '0.0.0.0',
         '192.168.1.240', '192.168.0.242','192.168.1.120']
```

I would like to know if there is any possibility to replace the IP Addresses in List1 to short strings with taking into consideration the repetitions between IP Addresses to get the List 2 below:

```
List1 = ['IP1','IP2','IP3','IP4','IP1','IP5','IP6'.'IP3']
```

The Repetitions of IP Addresses can be in anywhere (or location) in the List1.

Comment: It's not specific to IP addresses, you can iterate over `enumerate(set(List1))` and replace items in `List1` with a list comprehension.

Comment: at least try it , use enumerate method

Comment: I am not looking to replace the items between two lists. I am looking to replace the item in List1 with short string

Comment: Could you please give some more explanation about what I should do?

Comment: do you advise me to do something like that for i in enumerate(set(List1)):
    List2.append(i)?

Comment: I tried that for n, i in enumerate(List1):
    if i == '0.0.0.0':
        List1[n] = 'IP1'
    if i == '192.168.1.193':
        List1[n] = 'IP2'
    if i== '192.168.1.120':
        List1[n] = 'IP3'
    if i== '10.0.0.155':
        List1[n] = 'IP4'
    if i== '192.168.1.240':
        List1[n] = 'IP5'
    if i== '192.168.0.242':
        List1[n] = 'IP6'
        
print (List1)

Comment: I would like to know if there is more professional way instead of go through each item in list1 one by one and replace it

Comment: It removes all repeated IP Addresses and replace all IP Addresses from IP1 to IP6 with changing the order of IP Address. {'IP1': '192.168.1.193', 'IP2': '0.0.0.0', 'IP3': '192.168.1.120', 'IP4': '192.168.1.240', 'IP5': '192.168.0.242', 'IP6': '10.0.0.155'}

Comment: @Mohamed I can add an answer although are you sure you want to do this? This question might be an instance of [The X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yes, that I want to do because I am looking to plot the data thereafter so I can't remove any repetition of IP Addresses. All what I am looking to is to change all IP Addresses in List1 to IP'S (IP1,IP2, .....) without removing any repetition IP Addresses in the List1

Comment: A Dictionary is the way to go but, dictionaries cant have duplicate keys so it wouldn't work for what you are asking exactly unless you are okay with keeping duplicates together in a container which from what I'm seeing is not what your looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo:

- create an empty lookup dictionary
- create a number-variable for your placeholders
- iterate once through your list

  - if item not in dictionary

    - assign as key and as value assign it a placeholderstring
    - increment the placeholder number after adding
  - if item in dict already, ignore
- create a new list by looking up each element of your original list in the dict and use the placeholder string instead

to get a list of those placeholders:

```
data = ['0.0.0.0', '192.168.1.193', '192.168.1.120', '10.0.0.155', '0.0.0.0',
        '192.168.1.240', '192.168.0.242','192.168.1.120']

# create lookup dict
ips = {} 
n= 1
for thing in data:
    if thing not in ips:
        ips[thing] = f"IP{n}"
        n += 1

# create looked up value list
rv = [ips[k] for k in data]

print(rv)
```

Output:

```
['IP1', 'IP2', 'IP3', 'IP4', 'IP1', 'IP5', 'IP6', 'IP3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Toned down version:

```
dic = {}
for i in List1:
    if i not in dic:
        dic[i] = f"IP{len(dic)+1}"
```

After mapping elements in the original list to their name representations `IP$N`, you just map the values (strings) from keys(original IP addresses)
of the `dict` to the original list:

```
List1 = list(map(lambda x: dic[x], List1))
```